# Caching EF domain objects: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: entity-framework, caching, lazy-loading

I know this exception is caused by some properties being defined as `virtual` and therefore it's trying to load them lazily after the context has been disposed.

However, I don't want to load the entire object graph just to perform a fairly simple query. And if I try to cache the objects when the context is still alive, it tries to lazily load everything, and slows it down *considerably*.

Is there any way of performing the query, and then getting a disconnected result set, so that it doesn't try to lazily load things that I don't want it to? Or just turn of lazy loading for a specific query?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
return _cacheHelper.CacheGetOrInsert(CenterCacheKey, "tariffs", () => {
    using (var context = GetContext()) {
        return context.Tariffs
            .Include("Rates")
            .Include("Rates.Tiers")
            .Include("Rates.Tiers.Discounts")
            .Include("Discounts")
            .Include("Discounts.Regions")
            .ToList();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Ahh, just discovered `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` That seems to work.